# Java Selenium not using geckodriver

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

- Java 11
- Geckodriver v0.29.1-linux64
- Firefox 89.0.1 (64-bit)
- selenium-server v3.11.0
- Intellij

  ```
   // Firefox driver:
   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "lib/geckodriver");
   // Chromium driver:
   //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "lib/chromedriver");
   // Use either Firefox or Chromium driver:
   driver = new FirefoxDriver();
   // driver = new ChromeDriver();
   // URL to the tested web application
   baseUrl = "http://localhost:" + webPort + "/";
  ```

This gives me error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(boolean, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)'

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:136)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$000(GeckoDriverService.java:41)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.usingFirefoxBinary(GeckoDriverService.java:134)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:155)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:98)
at jtm.activity15.SeleniumWebDriverTest.setUp(SeleniumWebDriverTest.java:58)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.invokeMethod(RunBefores.java:33)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

As I understand this configuration is not even using geckodriver, but it is set to it?

Comment: Can you check your geckodriver path which is mentioned in the System.setProperty(), As this error occurs Java client unable to find the driver. Try to give the geckoDriver absolute path.

Comment: Added /home/student/Projects/u07/lib/geckodriver, still did not change anything.

Comment: is it a simple java project or a Maven project? if it is a Maven project can you just try with WebDriverManager? 

WebDriverManager.firefox().setup();

<dependency>
   <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
   <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
   <version>4.3.1</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();

Comment: When I tried to run this test with Eclipse everything worked as expected, still dont know why Intellij would not run this.